# Appium 1.5.0 not installing on Windows 8

Tags: appium

I have tried installing appium 1.5 released version on windows 7 , 8 and 10 , I am getting the following error

`

```
appium-chromedriver@2.8.0 install C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
odules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver
node install-npm.js
```

Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. info Chromedriver Install Installing Chromedriver version '2.21' for platfor in' and architecture '32' info Chromedriver Install Opening temp file to write chromedriver_win32 to.. info Chromedriver Install Downloading http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis /2.21/chromedriver_win32.zip... info Chromedriver Install Writing binary content to C:\Users\achauhan\AppDat cal\Temp\201621-7524-1cn5kzj\chromedriver_win32.zip... info Chromedriver Install Extracting C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Local\Temp\20
-7524-1cn5kzj\chromedriver_win32.zip to C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Local\Temp 621-7524-1cn5kzj\chromedriver_win32 info Chromedriver Install Creating C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod dules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win... info Chromedriver Install Copying unzipped binary, reading from C:\Users\ach n\AppData\Local\Temp\201621-7524-1cn5kzj\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe info Chromedriver Install Writing to C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedrive e... info Chromedriver Install C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules ium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe succe lly put in place

```
appium-selendroid-driver@1.2.2 install C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roaming\n
ode_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-selendroid-driver
node ./bin/install.js
```

info SelendroidInstaller Ensuring C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node ules\appium\node_modules\appium-selendroid-installer\selendroid\download exi info SelendroidInstaller Downloading Selendroid standalone server version 0. from https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/releases/download/0.17.0/sele id-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar --> C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roa \npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-selendroid-installer\selendroid nload\selendroid-server.jar info SelendroidInstaller Writing binary content to C:\Users\achauhan\AppData ming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-selendroid-installer\selend \download\selendroid-server.jar info SelendroidInstaller Selendroid standalone server downloaded info SelendroidInstaller Determining AndroidManifest location Error: Command 'jar tf C:\Users\achauhan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu \appium\node_modules\appium-selendroid-installer\selendroid\download\se roid-server.jar' errored out: Error: spawn jar ENOENT at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32 at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16) at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9) at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17) at ChildProcess. (lib/teen_process.js:31:14) at emitOne (events.js:77:13) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:169:7) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12 at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16) at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9) at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17) npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\node node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "appium" npm ERR! node v4.2.6 npm ERR! npm v2.14.12 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! appium-selendroid-driver@1.2.2 install: node ./bin/install.js npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
**npm ERR! Failed at the appium-selendroid-driver@1.2.2 install script 'node . /install.js'. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the appium-selendroid-driver pac , npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR! node ./bin/install.js npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm ERR! npm owner ls appium-selendroid-driver npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:** npm ERR! C:\Users\achauhan\npm-debug.log`

Answer (score 2):

Verify that `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is in PATH - it worked for me after adding this.
(`JAVA_HOME` contains the JDK root path.)

Comment: i tried everything else, but this is what solved my problem. The installation failed because it tried to run a 'jar' command but could not find it in the path. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with installation occurs when installing appium-selendroid-driver@1.2.2.

Install a Java Developer Kit, and this dependency should install correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it after following  below steps

1. Uninstall Appium GUI version
2. Go to c:\Users\xxxxx
3. use force command like
   npm install -f appium

You will find appium gets installed on

C:\Users\XXXXXXX\node_modules.bin

All you  have to do is now bind it to an environement varriable
You can then open command prompt and type appium to start it

Answer (score 0):

I came across a post talking about a similar problem. It was fixed by using another server jar file selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies_fixed.jar. It might be worth to try it.